# How are Battlepacks awarded?

Tags: battlefield-1

How are Battlepacks awarded in Battlefield 1? Are players chosen at random at the end of a match, or is there some skill/merit involved in determining who gets a Battlepack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Battlepack wikia page](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Battlepack):

> Battlepacks are content packages featured in Battlefield 4 and Battlefield Hardline, as well as the upcoming Battlefield 1 that add a new layer of **persistance** and element of **chance** to multiplayer.

This would imply that receiving a battlepack is based on chance rather than skill.

[Here](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/46530/20161026/battlefield-1-battlefield-1-guide-what-you-need-to-know-battlefield-1-what-you-need-to-know-battlepacks-what-you-need-to-know-battlepacks-battlefield-1-battlepacks.htm)'s another article that suggests you just get them randomly:

> Unlike in the past, Battlefield 1 players can earn battlepacks simply by playing the game.

[Here's](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-10-21-battlefield-1-battlepacks-scrap-puzzle-pieces-explained-4790) another that explicitly says it's random:

> The chances of you receiving one at the end of a match is random; we've heard some players not getting any for a number of hours, while we got our first at the end of our second match, so it's a case of keeping playing until they start landing in your lap.

Based on [this article](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/battlefield-1s-battlepacks-and-crafting-system-exp/1100-6444405/), it sounds a lot like the case system in CS:GO.

> Battlepacks are being simplified to a degree. There's now only a single type--a plain old Battlepack--you'll earn by playing.

Although, a major difference between cases and battlepacks is here:

> **Weapon skins or bonus items you're not interested in can be broken down into Scrap, a currency you can use to buy more Battlepacks**, including Enhanced and Superior versions. These Battlepacks can only be purchased with Scrap and guarantee you'll receive higher-rarity weapon skins. In other words, destroying things you don't want gives you a better chance to unlock weapon skins you'd otherwise be less likely to earn through a standard Battlepack.

Comment: I want to call BS on 'chance'. Everytime I've been in the top 5 in the end game screen, I've gotten one. I think it's something like luck + rank last game or something like that.

Comment: @ChaseC See, that's what I was confused on. I see that at the end of a game, 4 players are randomly selected at the bottom of the screen, but do those players listed with impressive in-match accomplishments get them too?

Comment: Good to know, i have been wondering too, havent seen a pattern, so random makes sense (but is also a little frustrating too). It would be awesome to know what that RNG roll breaks down to though, if anyone can see the code on PC.

Comment: @kaizerwolf I think the accomplishments give you a higher chance at getting them. I have no proof of this except this is what it feels like after every match I play.

Comment: Since I have the game I only have gotten one battlepack after around 20 rounds. How am I supposed to get new stuff if I get them so rarely? I hope it's not depending on skill, because that would mean that good players get more stuff to make them better while bad players don't get anything. When I got my battlepack it wasn't after a particularly good round, I was rather bad.

Comment: From my experience, you only get chance for a battlepack when you rank up.